# Unable to resolve akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out

Tags: akka, opendaylight, akka-persistence

I am trying to replace the default LevelDB in OpenDaylight with Apache Ignite which i am unable to do after making changes to the akka.conf file and deploying the akka-persistence-ignite jar that i found here. https://github.com/Romeh/akka-persistance-ignite

I am facing an issue in the following line of the source code (AbstractDataStoreClientActor class) where it throws a Runtime Exception.

```
   private static final Function1<ActorRef, ?> GET_CLIENT_FACTORY = ExplicitAsk.toScala(GetClientRequest::new);

   @SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:IllegalCatch")
   public static DataStoreClient getDistributedDataStoreClient(@Nonnull final ActorRef actor,
        final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) {
        return (DataStoreClient) Await.result(ExplicitAsk.ask(actor, GET_CLIENT_FACTORY,
            Timeout.apply(timeout, unit)), Duration.Inf());
```

which gives the following error

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://opendaylight-cluster-data/user/$a#-809157907]] after [30000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.actors.dds.GetClientRequest".
```

My question is how can i know the behavior of the actor to which the above message is sent? Is there any way to check if the actor has been created properly? What could be the reason for which the Ask method is going to timeout?

EDIT:::: error stack trace from karaf.log

```
2018-07-12T11:27:01,755 | ERROR | opendaylight-cluster-data-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18 | DistributedDataStoreClientActor  | 90 - com.typesafe.akka.slf4j - 2.5.11 | Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [member-1-frontend-datastore-config]. Last known sequence number [0]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at akka.japi.Util$.option(JavaAPI.scala:271) ~[84:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
    at akka.persistence.snapshot.japi.SnapshotStore.$anonfun$loadAsync$1(SnapshotStore.scala:20) ~[87:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.5.11]
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251) ~[323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209) ~[323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:288) ~[323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29) ~[323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29) ~[323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60) ~[323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) ~[84:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[84:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12) [323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81) [323:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.5.v20180316-130912-VFINAL-30a1428]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [84:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [84:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
```

Comment: Check the karaf.log for prior log messages  that might indicate why the actor wasn't created or died.

Comment: The actor has been created which i have confirmed by printing its path. I get this error in logs.                                                  2018-07-10T11:57:51,191 | ERROR | opendaylight-cluster-data-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 | DistributedDataStoreClientActor  | 90 - com.typesafe.akka.slf4j - 2.5.11 | Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [member-1-frontend-datastore-config]. Last known sequence number [0]   . Also where (class) exactly is the behavior of the actor for  'GetClientRequest' message specified?

Comment: "Persistence failure..." there's your answer - that's a non-recoverable error and akka kills the actor. It would seem  an issue related to ignite.

Comment: But there is no mention of any ignite in log trace. The issue is with the DistributedDatastoreClientActor. Where can i check the behavior of the corresponding actor for message of type 'GetClientRequest'? I am adding the error stack trace in the question. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with DistributedDatastoreClientActor - it is a side-effect of an issue with the persistence backend - see my previous comment. Notice that the error stack trace contains an NPE emanating from akka.persistence.snapshot.japi.SnapshotStore which indicates the backing SnapshotStore unexpectedly returned null from loadAsync. This points to the ignite plugin.